# GRE - Help allay my confusion between two options

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, word-in-context

Fill the blank with the most appropriate of the options

> Pundits do not believe that the sporadic calls for her ouster-outcries spurred by both her unusual life style and social policies-have compelled the monarch to seriously consider ____________.

a) abnegation

b) vacillation

c) castigation

d) asceticism

e) misanthropy

**Please guess the answer and then see my argument and my friends argument below**

**My Answer**
As from the sentence I am getting a sense that 'her' someone else . so I felt that 'castigation' is right . Another argument which I put keeping in mind it is a competitive exam (where we should logically eliminate irrelevant answers). If I choose [castigation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/castigation) mainly because of the word 'ouster'. ousting someone is a serious punishment , so castigation fits in here .

**My friends answer**
As from the sentence he assumes the 'her' refers to monarch and so he says that answer is abnegation .

Please help us find the right answer between the two . If you find that any other answer seems fit please tell that also , but with the reasoning behind it .

Comment: *Abnegation* is the only one that fits, but in this context it should surely be *abdication*.

Comment: "Castigation" is criticism. People don't "seriously consider" criticizing someone; they just do it. You're thinking of something like "censure", which is a more formal action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Original Text:** Pundits do not believe that the sporadic calls for her ouster-outcries spurred by both her unusual life style and social policies-have compelled the monarch to seriously consider ____________.

Let's simplify.  First remove the parenthetical phrase:

- **Original:** Pundits do not believe that the sporadic calls for her ouster <strike>-outcries spurred by both her unusual life style and social policies-</strike> have compelled the monarch to seriously consider ____________.

  **Result:** Pundits do not believe that the sporadic calls for her ouster have compelled the monarch to seriously consider ____________.

Simplify further by accepting the pundits belief as being true and replacing "ouster" with it's definition:

- **1.** <strike>Pundits do not believe that</strike> the sporadic calls for her ouster have **not** compelled the monarch to seriously consider ____________.
- **2.** The sporadic calls for her **removal from office** have not compelled the monarch to seriously consider __________.**

Note that "sporadic" is contrasted with "seriously".  Nobody would *seriously* consider a removal from office just because of some *sporadic* calls for such. (Especially for the petty reasons we deleted earlier.)

Now the question is who is being called for an ouster?  There are two choices: the monarch ***herself*** (if the monarch is a woman) or someone that the monarch (male or female) might be compelled to "oust". It should be obvious now that her=monarch.  That would be the easier and more sensible way to read the sentence.  (This is an example of  [cataphora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataphora).)

But just for fun, let's consider "your choice": that it is **someone else** the monarch is going to act upon.  Let's call her "Mary".  It would not make any sense for the monarch to "verbally reproach" (castigate) Mary due to a few discontented voices crying for an ***ouster***.  Note that *castigation* is never used in the sense of "removing someone from office".<sup>1</sup>  *Castigation* simply does not fit.

**Your friend is correct.  We must consider her=monarch and blank=abnegation.**  It fits and makes sense.  It's not really *that* complicated, but I wanted to cover all bases. :)

As an additional note, @StoneyB and @DrMoishePippik deftly pointed out that ***abdication*** is the proper word to use in this case.  See [*this link*](http://grammarist.com/usage/abdicate-abnegate-abrogate/) for a short explanation.

---

<sup>1. *castigate* is (IMO) ill-defined in most all dictionaries. The modern usage of the word is almost exclusively a harsh verbal reproach, yet every dictionary blithely includes "punish severely" and sometimes "flog", often including some archaic quote (and often the same quote in every dictionary).  One is hard pressed to find modern sentences using 'castigate' as an actual physical punishment.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**Abnegation** *can* mean renunciation, but more often means an act of self-denial or abstinence. However, it is the best of the choices available, since **castigation** implies blaming someone else. Perhaps a better word would be**abdication**, to leave her throne.
*Her* must refer to the monarch, since there is no other antecedent for that pronoun.
**Asceticism** would have made sense if there were only "outcries spurred by her unusual life style", presumably hedonistic, but would not apply to complaints against her social policies.